# Excel 2010 Conditional Formatting Groups with Borders

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of schools that I would like to conditionally format.  I would like each school to have a heavy border around and different color bands per school to set if apart.  Can this be done in Excel? If so, how? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is sorted (it will look pretty ugly if it isn't) select the columns you want to format. Go to conditional formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format. In the formula field type `=IF($B2<>$B1,TRUE,FALSE)` and set your format to set the border beneath each school. As for the alternating row colors, depending on how many schools you have do the same steps as above but use `=IF($B1="AB Elementary",mod(row(),2),FALSE)` in the formula. Repeat for each unique school name.

Comment: If you have a lot of schools, you may consider using a pair of alternating color bands and using an OR statement in your conditional format like this: `=IF(OR($B1="AB Elementary",$B1="Barnes Elementary"),MOD(ROW(),2),FALSE)` and `=IF(OR($B1="Smith Elementary",$B1="Jones Elementary"),MOD(ROW(),2),FALSE)`